# Suppose $n_i-n_{i-1}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence. Prove $\exists T\in \operatorname{End}_\mathbb F(V)$ such that $n_i=\dim \ker(T^i)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space, $\dim V=n$.

$0<n_1<n_2\cdots<n_3<\cdots<n_{k-1}<n_k=n$ such that $n_i\in \mathbb N$

Suppose $n_i-n_{i-1}$ is a decrease ($\leq$) monotonic sequence.

Prove that exist $T\in \operatorname{End}_\mathbb F(V)$ such that $n_i=\dim \ker(T^i)$

I have no idea how to start with this proof , I know that

$\ker(T)\subset \ker(T^2)\cdots \subset \ker(T^n)$

I will be grateful for some help\hints.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Produce a matrix $J$ in [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) such that the number of blocks associated with the eigenvalue zero with size at least $i$ is $n_i - n_{i-1}$.